# Linux command to return all files that start with TEMP but do not end with double digits

Tags: files, ls, wildcards

What is the Linux command to return all files that start with TEMP but do not end with double digits?

I think it should look something like this:

```
ls -l TEMP*[!0-9][!0-9]
```

but the results of my search are omitting some results it seems.

Answer (score 9):

With GNU and most modern BSDs `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'TEMP*' ! -name "*[0-9][0-9]"
```

POSIXly:

```
find . ! -name . -prune  -type f -name 'TEMP*' ! -name "*[0-9][0-9]"
```

`ksh` or `bash -O extglob` or `zsh -o kshglob`:

```
ls -ld TEMP*@([^0-9]?|?[^0-9]) [T]EMP TEMP?
```

Comment: The extglob solution will miss all files which match `TEMP?`, as well as the file `TEMP` itself.

Comment: Note that if there's no file called `TEMP` but one called `[T]EMP`, it will be listed (except with `zsh` which will cancel the command).

Answer (score 3):

If your shell is `ksh`, or `bash` with the `extglob` option (`shopt -s extglob` to enable), then

```
ls -d TEMP!(*[0-9][0-9])
```

should work. If you want to search recursively and globstar is enabled (`set -o globstar` in `ksh93`, `shopt -s globstar` in `bash`) then you should be able to do that as

```
ls -d -- **/TEMP!(*[0-9][0-9])
```

(note that it does not traverse hidden directories by default)

For example, if

```
$ ls -d -- **/TEMP*
TEMP12345  TEMP123ab  TEMPabc12  TEMPabcde  tests/TEMP12345  tests/TEMP123ab  tests/TEMPabc12  tests/TEMPabcde
```

then

```
$ ls -d -- **/TEMP!(*[0-9][0-9])
TEMP123ab  TEMPabcde  tests/TEMP123ab  tests/TEMPabcde
```

The equivalent in `zsh` is:

```
setopt extendedglob
ls -d -- **/TEMP^*[0-9][0-9]
```

Comment: Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks, I like the extended globbing version!                         ls TEMP!(*[0-9][0-9])

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is okay: looking for everything starting with temp and not ending with two number.
Unfortunately, I think you made a syntax mistake.
You should replace ! by ^. So now you are searching for files like:
temp*99 and temp*!!.